# Coerce R matrix to dgTMatrix inside a function

Tags: r, matrix

Given a matrix object in R, it's easy to coerce it to a sparse matrix in triplet format:

```
library(Matrix)
m <- matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.5),10,10)
m <- as(1*m, "dgTMatrix")
```

But, what is the correct way to do this inside an R function (i.e., without attaching the Matrix library)? I know that `m <- Matrix::as(1*m, "dgTMatrix")` is not correct, but suspect it will be something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would do something like

```r
if (requireNamespace("Matrix", quietly = TRUE))
    m <- as(m, "dgTMatrix")
else
    stop("package ", sQuote("Matrix"), " not found on library path")
```

to load the package as necessary, without attaching it.  This has the effect of registering coercion (and other) methods without making all of the objects exported by `Matrix` available to the user.

If your function is part of an R package with `Matrix` listed in `Imports`, then you could do

```r
m <- as(m, "dgTMatrix")
```

directly, without `requireNamespace`.  If `Matrix` is instead listed in `Suggests`, then you would need to use `requireNamespace` as above.  In both cases, you would want `Imports` to include package `methods` and `NAMESPACE` to contain the directive `importFrom(methods, as)`.

Tangentially, note that that your `1*m`, effectively coercing `m` from `integer` to `double`, is unnecessary.  The coercion method does that work for you:

```r
selectMethod("coerce", c("matrix", "dgTMatrix"))
```

```
Method Definition:

function (from, to = "dgTMatrix", strict = TRUE) 
{
    x <- as.double(from)
    nz <- isN0(x)
    new("dgTMatrix", Dim = dim(from), Dimnames = .M.DN(from), 
        i = row(from)[nz] - 1L, j = col(from)[nz] - 1L, x = x[nz])
}
<bytecode: 0x1079ded68>
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        from     to         
target  "matrix" "dgTMatrix"
defined "matrix" "dgTMatrix"
```

Answer (score 0):

For use in a function that will be part of an R package, I think this should work:

```
m <- matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.5),10,10)
m_ <- Matrix::spMatrix(nrow(m), 
                       ncol(m), 
                       i = which(m != 0, arr.ind = T)[,1], 
                       j = which(m != 0, arr.ind = T)[,2], 
                       x = rep(1,sum(m)))
```